# Select 2 random items from an RSS feed

Tags: c#, list, random, rss

I have an RSS feed which I am currently displaying 2 items, what I am wanting is for every time the page is reloaded that a different 2 items are displayed. The code I currently have is

```
//BBC UK 
string RssFeedUrl = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml?edition=uk";


List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
try
{
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);

    var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item").Take(2)
    select new
    {
        title = x.Element("title").Value,
        link = x.Element("link").Value,
        pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
        description = x.Element("description").Value
    });

    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        Feeds f = new Feeds
        {
            Title = i.title,
            Link = i.link,
            PublishDate = i.pubDate,
            Description = i.description
        };

        feeds.Add(f);         
    }
```

How to a change this to select 2 random items each time the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Random` class to generate two random numbers and take those two elements from collection.

```
    int[] randints =  new int[2];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    randints[0] = rnd.Next(0, xDoc.Descendants("item").Count()); // creates first random number


    do 
    {
        randints[1] = rnd.Next(0, xDoc.Descendants("item").Count()); // creates second random number
    }while (randints[1] == randints[0]); // make sure that you don't have duplicates.


var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
     .Skip(randints[0]-1)
     .Take(1)
     .Concat(xDoc.Descendants("item")
                .Skip(randints[1]-1)
                .Take(1))
     .Select(x=> new
      {
           title = x.Element("title").Value,
           link = x.Element("link").Value,
           pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
           description = x.Element("description").Value
      });

foreach (var i in items)
{
    Feeds f = new Feeds
    {
        Title = i.title,
        Link = i.link,
        PublishDate = i.pubDate,
        Description = i.description
    };

    feeds.Add(f);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would better cache this values for some time instead of requesting each time, but if performance is not critical here is one solution

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
var rnd = new Random();
var twoRand = xDoc.Descendants("item")
              .OrderBy(e => rnd.Next()).Take(2).Select(...)
              .ToList();
```